# Objective-c HTTP Basic authentication

Tags: objective-c, authentication, httpwebrequest, lighthouse

How would i go about replicating this in objective-c

```
curl -u rick@email.com:mypassword http://foo.lighthouseapp.com/projects.xml
```

I've been playing around with the ASIHTTPRequest library but can't seem to figure it out,

obviously sending my request like so returns an authentication error:

```
-(void)submit:(id)sender {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ldn.lighthouseapp.com/projects/63254-londonist-20/tickets.xml"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request startSynchronous];
    NSError *error = [request error];
    if (!error) {
        NSString *response = [request responseString];
        NSLog(@"response:%@",response);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error:%@",error);
    }
}
```

This is probably very simple i'm just missing something pretty major

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[From ASIHTTPRequest Documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#specifying_a_username_and_password_to_use_in_the_url)

[With a Request Header](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#setting_request_headers)

```
[request addRequestHeader:@"Authorization"
                    value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",
                           [ASIHTTPRequest base64forData:
                            [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", theUsername, thePassword]
                             dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]]];
```

Answer (score 14):

If don't want use any frameworks (like me) you can do in the next way:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://api.github.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", login, password];
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];
[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request
         completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
             if (!error) {
              NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
              NSLog(@"%@",responseDictionary);
          }
         }] resume];
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASIHTTPRequest, this is all that is needed:

```
 request.shouldPresentCredentialsBeforeChallenge = YES;
 [request addBasicAuthenticationHeaderWithUsername:@"USER" andPassword:@"PASSWORD"];
```